# How do I concatenate an escape to a string?

Tags: python, binary, escaping, arrays

My goal is to convert a binary value into the "bytestring" format python interprets it as. Example: 1111111111111111 would be 0xffff and when interpreted be represented as \xff\xff\xff . If there is a more direct method of converting it to this format please let me know as that would be ideal, as of now I'm using brute force with this solution:

```
hexnum = hex(int("11110100111100001110110101111011",2))
hexstring = str(hexnum)[2:]
finalstr = ""
i = 0
while(i<=len(hexstring)):
    finalstr+= hexstring[i:i+2]
    finalstr+= "\x" 
    i=i+2
```

My problem is when:

```
print repr(finalstr)
```

I receive the error

> ValueError: invalid \x escape

How do I properly concatenate the escape or how do I convert a binary string into the hex bytearray format python uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) like this:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = "11110100111100001110110101111011"
>>> binascii.unhexlify(format(int(s, 2), 'x'))
'\xf4\xf0\xed{'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3:

```
v = int("11110100111100001110110101111011",2)
v.to_bytes((v.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
```

produces a bytes value represented by the bits:

```
>>> v = int("11110100111100001110110101111011",2)
>>> v.to_bytes((v.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
b'\xf4\xf0\xed{'
```

You can't just prepend the `\x` syntax; that only works in string literals.

In Python 2, you could use a `bytearray()` instead, as it takes a list of integers in the range 0-255:

```
v = int("11110100111100001110110101111011",2)
bytes_list = []
while v:
    v, one_byte = divmod(v, 256)
    bytes_list.append(one_byte)
str(bytearray(bytes_list[::-1]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> v = int("11110100111100001110110101111011",2)
>>> bytes_list = []
>>> while v:
...     v, one_byte = divmod(v, 256)
...     bytes_list.append(one_byte)
... 
>>> bytearray(bytes_list[::-1])
bytearray(b'\xf4\xf0\xed{')
>>> str(bytearray(bytes_list[::-1]))
'\xf4\xf0\xed{'
```